# Comparing CPU benchmark

Tags: cpu, performance, intel-core-i7, amd-ryzen

I have a laptop with the Intel Core I7-6700HQ.
In the next days my workstation will be ready, with a Ryzen 7 2700x.
As you can see in this [benchmark](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-6700HQ-vs-AMD-Ryzen-7-2700X/m34954vs3958)
the overall difference is **ONLY** 64%.
This sounds quite strange to me for many reasons.

1. Ryzen 7 is designed for desktop instead of laptop
2. Ryzen 7 has twice the number of cores and threads wrt the i7
3. Ryzen 7 is at minimum of 3.7 ghz, while the other is at 2.6

My reasoning is the following: I expect the Ryzen 7 to be around 3 time faster, so 300% instead of just 64%, because the number of core and threads is double and the ghz is around 1/3 above.
Is my reasoning wrong?
Why so few difference between them?

Comment: Look into the sub-parts of the benchmark. The single core benefits of the Ryzen is only 40% while the multicore is 185%. The overall result is a combination of factors. The Ryzen has more cores and is newer, but the Intel tech is still pretty solid, especially considering the lower clock speed.

Comment: [Desktop to Desktop comparison](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-6700K-vs-AMD-Ryzen-7-2700X/3502vs3958) shows that the desktop 6700K is only outperformed in multicore tests. The 6700K easily matches the Ryzen and even outperforms it in places. Multicore depends a lot on the tasks being done, not all applications can benefit from it and it largely benefits things like games (where physics and graphics and audio tasks can be separated out) and video transcoding. Inherently linear tasks do not benefit from multicore and the benchmark calculation is a reflection of that.